# How to stop click event on Parent element when clicking the child element

Tags: reactjs

I am having a button inside a div. And on their on click events i am performing two different functions. The requirement is that when the child element is clicked, then parent element onClick event should not trigger.

```
redirectCTD() 
{
   console.log("inside Parent Element");
   //other stuffs to do
}  

openTileModal(toolName) 
{
  console.log("inside Child Element");
  this.setState({
   isOpenTile: true,
   toolSelected: toolName
  });
}



<div className="col-md-12 tool ctd_tool" onClick={this.redirectCTD}>
                          <button onClick={this.openTileModal.bind(this,"ctd")}><img src={require("../../../images/icon-expand-blue.png")} /></button>
</div>
```

I have tried to use `event.stopPropogation` and `event.preventDefault` inside `openTileModal()` method.

```
openTileModal(toolName,event) 
{
  event.stopPropogation();
  console.log("inside Child Element");
  this.setState({
   isOpenTile: true,
   toolSelected: toolName
  });
}
```

But that is not working, i'm getting error in console, "`e.stopPropogation is not a function`". Can someone help me to achieve the objective. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You spelled `Propagation` wrong.  Try this:

```
openTileModal(toolName,event) 
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("inside Child Element");
  this.setState({
   isOpenTile: true,
   toolSelected: toolName
  });
}
```

Comment: No problem at all!